# Asterisk PHPAGI response code

Tags: asterisk, agi

I have been trying to find a website that lists all the code that I can response back to the caller's server. Right now I can do either:

```
$agi->answer();
$agi->busy();
```

I am looking forward to be sending like, payment required, etc. Please help point me to the right path if you know it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Look here: http://phpagi.sourceforge.net/phpagi2/docs/elementindex_phpAGI.html

Most actions are preformed via executing commands. For example, to reproduce a recording use exec: http://phpagi.sourceforge.net/phpagi2/docs/phpAGI/AGI.html#methodexec

```
$agi->exec('Playback','hello-world');
```